# Webpack: How to generate separate css files from sass

Tags: sass, webpack

Currently I have this webpack (Angular2 seed) project. With this project I have some css which depends on which client opens the page (multi brand platform).

As of now I'm generating css files using the ExtractTextPlugin, this works pretty well except for now my images etc. are all dumped in the dist root, but I can probably solve those things.

What bothers me slightly is that this also generates a "cssentrypoint.js" and "cssentrypoint.map.js". I guess it's the default behaviour but does anyone know if there is a simple solution to just generate the sass in the build script (so it still watches for changes) and not the JS?

I'll share my webpack.common config which applies to all, the out is configured to be something like [name].[chunkhash].js

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
var CopyWebpackPlugin = (CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'), CopyWebpackPlugin.default || CopyWebpackPlugin);
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
var glob = require('glob');

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Prepaid Service Provider',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = {

  /*
   * Static metadata for index.html
   *
   * See: (custom attribute)
   */
  metadata: METADATA,

  /*
   * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
   * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
   * You can pass false to disable it.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
   */
   //cache: false,

  /*
   * The entry point for the bundle
   * Our Angular.js app
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
   */
  entry: {

    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
    'vendor':    './src/vendor.browser.ts',
    'main':      './src/main.browser.ts',
    'eneco':    './src/style/css/someclient.scss',
     'nuon':     './src/style/css/someotherclient.scss'

  },

  /*
   * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
   */
  resolve: {

    /*
     * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
     */
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', 'scss'],

    // Make sure root is src
    root: helpers.root('src'),

    // remove other default values
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],

    alias: {
      // legacy imports pre-rc releases
      'angular2': helpers.root('node_modules/@angularclass/angular2-beta-to-rc-alias/dist/beta-17')
    },

  },

  /*
   * Options affecting the normal modules.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
   */
  module: {

    /*
     * An array of applied pre and post loaders.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-preloaders-module-postloaders
     */
    preLoaders: [

      /*
       * Tslint loader support for *.ts files
       *
       * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
       */
       // { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'tslint-loader', exclude: [ helpers.root('node_modules') ] },

      /*
       * Source map loader support for *.js files
       * Extracts SourceMaps for source files that as added as sourceMappingURL comment.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/source-map-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [
          // these packages have problems with their sourcemaps
          helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular'),
        ]
      }

    ],

    /*
     * An array of automatically applied loaders.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to.
     * This means they are not resolved relative to the configuration file.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
     */
    loaders: [

      /*
       * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
       *
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
      },

      /*
       * Json loader support for *.json files.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },

      /* Raw loader support for *.html
       * Returns file content as string
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
       */
      {
        test: [/\.html$/],
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
      },
      {
        test: [/\.jpg$/, /\.jpeg$/, /\.png$/],
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/i, loader:
        ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css!sass'])

      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=.+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=./fonts/[hash].[ext]"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=.+)?$/,
        loader: 'file?name=./fonts/[hash].[ext]'
      },
    ]

  },

  /*
   * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
   */
  plugins: [

    /*
     * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
     * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
     */
    new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

    /*
     * Plugin: OccurenceOrderPlugin
     * Description: Varies the distribution of the ids to get the smallest id length
     * for often used ids.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurrenceorderplugin
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#minimize
     */
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),

    /*
     * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
     * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
     * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
     */
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
    }),

    /*
     * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
     *
     * Copies project static assets.
     *
     * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
     */
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: 'src/assets',
      to: 'assets'
    }]),

    new ExtractTextPlugin("assets/css/[name].css", {allChunks: false}) ,

    /*
     * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
     * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
     * which changes every compilation.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
     */
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),

    /*
     * Plugin: HtmlHeadConfigPlugin
     * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
     *
     * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
     * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
     * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
     *
     * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
     * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
     *
     * Example:
     *  Adding this plugin configuration
     *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
     *    headTags: { ... }
     *  })
     *
     *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
     *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
     *
     * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
     */
    new HtmlElementsPlugin({
      headTags: require('./head-config.common')
    })
  ],

  /*
   * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
   * Description: Node configuration
   *
   * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
   */
  node: {
    global: 'window',
    crypto: 'empty',
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }

};
```

## Update

In addition webpack generates those JS files and also embeds them, this includes css files which I want to optionally show...